# Problema con método .click() de Jquery y un iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Hay algún tipo de problema al utilizar el método .click() sobre un iframe que ocupa toda la pantalla?

```
        $("section").click(function () {
            alert("hola");
        });
```

El iframe está dentro del section, es un visor de mapas, y ambos ocupan todo el tamaño posible de la pantalla. El problema está que al hacer click, no funciona, en cambio, si quito el iframe, sí. Haces click y sale el mensaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación relativa a event bubbling especificada en:
https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling

Establece que los eventos se propagan hacia arriba en la jerarquía hasta el tope del documento.

> This upward propagation will continue up to and including the Document.

Por otra parte la documentación relativa a documentos embebidos en la siguiente url: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.5

Establece que los documentos asi incluidos son completamente independientes.

> An embedded document is entirely independent of the document in which it is embedded. For instance, relative URIs within the embedded document resolve according to the base URI of the embedded document, not that of the main document. An embedded document is only rendered within another document (e.g., in a subwindow); it remains otherwise independent.

Por lo que se concluye que la propagación de eventos no pasa desde el contenido del iframe hacia fuera de el.